# ImportError: cannot import name '_app_ctx_stack' from 'flask'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I used to run my application simply by installing the requirements txt file, but today seems to be different because now I get an error:

[image: import error]

I did `brew install python-setuptools` but the situations seems to be the same.

What do you think I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please [edit] to indicate the versions of flask and flask-sql-alchemy you have installed. Did you recently _upgrade_ any of your packages?

Comment: Welcome. Please edit your post so as to share [code, data and **error tracebacks** as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557).

Answer (score -1):

'_app_ctx_stack' is removed in Flask 2.3. I solved the issue by using a previous version of Flask.